# Host multiple sites with same physical path?

Tags: windows, iis, asp.net

I have read a few articles on hosting multiple sites using the same IP address, however didn't really come across an article which covers my situation.

I have a main site, and several 'sister' sites - that have different content and page title.

All the data, for the main site and the sister sites, is contained in one database.

At the moment, there is only one IIS entry for the site.

This works fine, however, sometimes, the data displayed does get mixed up. 
For example :

I requested `www.sisterSiteA.com`, and I got the title and the content for `www.sisterSiteB.com`.

So, I was thinking of having one IIS entry per sister site, to keep things separate. However, the database is still shared and the physical path and IP address for each of those sister sites will be the same as well. Just the host name will vary.

Is this possible and recommended or is there another way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can "Host multiple sites with same physical path" but you need server technology, for example Server.Transfer() in the .NET world (although it does seem like you have a mechanism for doing this) or URL renaming...

I will point out, that for SEO, your idea is flawed. It also means, that if I copy the URL of your site, I'd never get back to that page...

The entire thing (using 1 path but to show different content based upon some criteria) would be a laborious and logical nightmare.

I would personally use different subdomains. It is easier to manage, of course it doesn't matter what the domain of the site is in regards of what database is being used (unless you have a very bespoke set up). Each subdomain can be indexed by Google as any other site, but the fact they are subdomains means they will not be treated as totally different sites where as sisterSiteA and sisterSiteB are totally independant in regards to domain names (only just clever humans can see the link)

Comment: Thanks, Dave. These sites have been around for years actually, so creating sub-domains now is out of question. I was just asked to fix this content being mixed up issue. And, I thought one IIS entry per site could be the first step? So, if we don't take sub-domains into consideration, do you think one IIS entry per site would be good move? Or perhaps there is something else I could do?

Comment: Well, one IIS entry per site means each domain has it's own site which is probably the most common way of setting up the sites... Or am I missing the point?

Comment: At the moment, there is only one IIS entry for all the sites. So, when I hit www.SiteA.com, the content related to the sister site is displayed. So, there is no URL redirection as such. Because, even when I do hit a different URL, redirection is pretty much to the same site, with the sister site URL and ID passed as parameters, based on which the data is fetched. Makes sense?